# Selecting different regions of a worldmap

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d for iPhone, how can I turn a selected portion of the screen into a menu item with  selector functionality?

Imagine a worldmap with curved borders between different regions. When the player touches one of these regions, there should be a selector / callback for it. Sort of like a standard menu, but without making a label or an image selectable. Instead, what I want is to be able to specify the clickable area manually.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a CCLayer that will contain this custom region? CCLayer already implements the touch delegates, and you could easily start capturing the regions by setting self.isTouchEnabled to true.

Answer (score 0):

Define the areas of your world map manually, ideally as rectangles for polygons you'll need to look up polygon intersection test. Then just use CGRectContainsPoint with all rectangles and the touch point. If the touch is inside a world area, run whatever code needs to run.